# Mapping Tuples in ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

I'm converting some flow code to ts and am not sure how to do the equivalent of this flow code in TS:

```
declare function $nullableAwait<T>(p: Promise<T> | T): T | null;
export function genAllNull<T: Iterable<mixed>>(...promises: T): Promise<$TupleMap<T, typeof $nullableAwait>> {
  return Promise.all([].map.call(promises, genNull));
}
```

Specifically I can't find anything in TS that is the equivalent of `$TupleMap` in flow, which allows me to map an array of types from one type to another

Comment: This is nice code :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can map tuples as you would any other type since typescript 3.1 (see this [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063))

If my understading of your code is right (and I don't claim to know flow). This would be waht you are looking for:

```
type Unpack<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T; 
type UnpackAllOrNull<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]:  Unpack<T[P]> |null
}
export function genAllNull<T extends Promise<any>[]>(...promises: T): Promise<UnpackAllOrNull<T>> {
  return null!;
}

let a = genAllNull(Promise.resolve(1),Promise.resolve("")) //Promise<[number | null, string | null]>
```